# Rails: how can I get unique values from column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unique

How can I get unique values from column in the table?
For example, I have this Products table:

```
ID NAME CATEGORY
1 name1 1st_cat
2 name2 2nd_cat
3 name3 1st_cat
```

Here I want to get only 2 values - 1st_cat and 2nd_cat:

```
<%Products.each do |p|%>
<%=p.category%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: also u can group Product.group("category_id")

Comment: All of the possible ways below - It should be noted that Products.uniq.pluck(:category) is the most efficient way

Comment: Just an afterthought; if your Model names are plural, you're doing it wrong, in terms of Rails' opinion.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Two more ways:

```
Product.select(:category).map(&:category).uniq # Ruby does the work

Product.uniq.pluck(:category) # DB does the work (superior)
```

For **Rails >= 5.1** use:

```
Product.distinct.pluck(:category) # DB does the work (superior)
```

...because `Relation#uniq` was [deprecated](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations).

Comment: I was exactly looking for this : 
Products.pluck(:category).uniq

Superb! +1 :)

Comment: This will pull all the products into a Ruby array, rather than doing the work in the database.

Comment: @superluminary is pulling all the products into a Ruby array, rather than having the DB do the work recommended?

Comment: Normally you want the db to do the job - Ruby array means extra memory consumption, and the db would do it faster normally

Comment: `User.uniq.pluck(:source)` produces `SELECT DISTINCT "users"."source" FROM "users"` so I don't think it is loading all records into a ruby array.

Comment: @RafaelOliveira Correct, but that only applies to the second of the two ways shown. `Products.uniq.pluck(:category)` makes the db do the work, but the first way of `Products.select(:category).map(&:category).uniq` is equivalent to `Products.pluck(:cateogry).uniq` (notice the `pluck` and `uniq` methods are reversed), which pulls all the categories into an array in memory and makes Ruby do the work.

Comment: To clarify my last comment, the reason for the behavior described is because there are two different `uniq` methods being called. ActiveRecord has a `uniq` method that converts into `DISTINCT` in SQL, but then Ruby's Array class also has a `uniq` method that selects unique elements from an array. Meanwhile, AR's `pluck` and `map` methods execute the converted SQL statement and return the results converted to an array, so when you call `uniq` after `pluck` or `map`, you're actually calling the array method instead of the AR method.

Comment: For **Rails >= 5.1** use `Products.distinct.pluck(:category)`

Comment: @davegson I edited in your comment. Thanks for the update - you just helped me. Edit: Seeing as you have edit privileges too, may I kindly suggest that you edit in the correct answer should you ever come across a similar situation?

Comment: @Gary, thanks - updated. I followed suite on OP, but should have corrected from the beginning.

Answer (score 27):

I think you can do this:

```
<% Products.select("DISTINCT(CATEGORY)").each do |p| %>
<%= p.category %>
<% end %>
```

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

Comment: I'm a Rails newbie myself (just working through the tutorials now ;-) ) I Googled it.

Comment: works only if you want 1 column, other column are not selected

Answer (score 13):

This does all the work in the database server. The result is a simple array.

```
<% Product.distinct(:category).pluck(:category).each do |category|
    <%= category %>
<% end %>
```

Rails will generate SQL that works on any database (Postgres, MySQL, etc).

```
SELECT DISTINCT "products"."category" FROM "products"
```

Answer (score 9):

I suggest to use `Products.all.distinct.pluck(:category)` because `uniq` has been deprecated since rails 5 and it will be removed on rails 5.1

Answer (score 6):

Try this (in the rails console)

```
Product.group(:category)

Product.group(:category).each { |p| p.name }
```

Comment: That will only work on MySql databases (possibly sqlite as well but definitely not good on Postgres or MSSQL

Comment: Works on sqlite

Comment: You have to: Product.select(:category).group(:category) to get this to work on Postgresql (and I guess MSSQL).

Answer (score 5):

For postgres

```
<% Product.select("DISTINCT ON (category) *").each do |category|
    <%= category %>
    <%= name %>
<% end %>
```

---

## Update

even better

```
<% Product.select(%(DISTINCT ON (category) "#{Product.table_name}".*)).each do |category|
    <%= category %>
    <%= name %>
<% end %>
```

because it can return wrong columns when you do `joins` (e.g. returns `id` column from joined table, but not `products`)

Comment: Voted up because when you require the whole active record relation instead of plucked values array, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you or anyone want to get two or more attributes from a table like ***products***, based on a distinct feature of an attribute, only this solution will help you for **Rails >= 5.1**

```
distinct_products = Product.select("DISTINCT ON (category) *")

# it's an active record relation class.
> distinct_products.class
=> Product::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

**N.B.** Don't use `.pluck()` on the `distinct_products`. It will reselect from the ***products*** table and the distinct feature will not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to get unique output and was trying the 'uniq' method unsuccessfully. Tried several solutions posted here unsuccessfully. I'm using devise which gives me access to the `current_user` method and working with two tables, one being a join (an item has_many :things).

This solution ultimately worked for me :

```
@current_user.things.select(:item_fk).distinct.each do |thing|
 <%= thing.item.attribute %>
<% end %>
```