# Rails: select unique values from a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I already have a working solution, but I would really like to know why this doesn't work:

```
ratings = Model.select(:rating).uniq
ratings.each { |r| puts r.rating }
```

It selects, but don't print unique values, it prints all values, including the duplicates. And it's in the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

Comment: Another example with uniq


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369812/rails-how-can-i-get-unique-values-from-column

Answer (score 557, accepted):

```rb
Model.select(:rating)
```

The result of this is a collection of `Model` objects. Not plain ratings. And from `uniq`'s point of view, they are completely different. You can use this:

```rb
Model.select(:rating).map(&:rating).uniq
```

or this (most efficient):

```rb
Model.uniq.pluck(:rating)
```

## Rails 5+

```rb
Model.distinct.pluck(:rating)
```

#### Update

Apparently, as of rails 5.0.0.1, it works only on "top level" queries, like above. Doesn't work on collection proxies ("has_many" relations, for example).

```rb
Address.distinct.pluck(:city) # => ['Moscow']
user.addresses.distinct.pluck(:city) # => ['Moscow', 'Moscow', 'Moscow']
```

In this case, deduplicate after the query

```rb
user.addresses.pluck(:city).uniq # => ['Moscow']
```

Comment: I did a:
    group(:rating).collect { |r| r.rating }
Since map == collect, where can I read about this sintax you used (&:rating)? I don't see this in Ruby's documentation.

Comment: @user1261084: see [Symbol#to_proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) to understand .map(&:rating). [PragDave explains](http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2005/11/symbolto_proc.html)

Comment: @Sergio, since Model.select(:rating) returns an array of Model objects, what's the use of specifying select on a column? I am finding it hard to grok how it is different from Model.all.

Comment: @Salil: if you're referring to my second line, then `select(:rating)` gets all Model records, but only fills rating field (to save bandwidth). Then we transform these Model objects to plain rating values, which we can `uniq`.

Comment: It's worth noting that `Model.uniq.pluck(:rating)` is the most efficient way of doing this - this generates SQL which use `SELECT DISTINCT` rather than applying `.uniq` to an array

Comment: @Mikey's comment is the right way. No idea why this answer is marked as correct. It's a exploding bomb if run in production with lots of data

Comment: @HenleyChiu: what do you mean? The answer suggests using `pluck` too.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I would just get rid of the 2 prior answers, and just show the pluck one. It's the only efficient way.

Comment: In Rails 5, `Model.uniq.pluck(:rating)` will be `Model.distinct.pluck(:rating)`

Comment: If you want to select unique values from has_many relationship you can always do `Model.related_records.group(:some_column).pluck(:some_column)`

Comment: There is a wrong information in the answer; `Model.select(:rating)` does not return an array of `Model` objects, it actually returns an instance of `Model::ActiveRecord_Relation`.

Comment: @FooBarZoo: now yes. But 6 years ago maybe it was returning an array.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `Model.distinct.pluck(:rating)` works for me on Rails 4.2.5 too.

Comment: Not working on rails 7

Answer (score 102):

If you're going to use `Model.select`, then you might as well just use `DISTINCT`, as it will return only the unique values. This is better because it means it returns less rows and should be slightly faster than returning a number of rows and then telling Rails to pick the unique values.

```
Model.select('DISTINCT rating')
```

Of course, this is provided your database understands the `DISTINCT` keyword, and most should.

Comment: `Model.select("DISTINCT rating").map(&:rating)` to get an array of just the ratings.

Comment: Great for those with legacy apps using Rails 2.3

Comment: Yes..this works fantastic - however, but it only returns the DISTINCT attribute. How can you return the entire Model object as long as its distinct? So that you will have access to all of the attributes in the model in instances where the attribute is unique.

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland If you want a Model object, that would need to be instantiated from a record in the table. But you're not selecting a record just a unique value (from what may be multiple records).

Answer (score 78):

This works too.

```
Model.pluck("DISTINCT rating")
```

Comment: I believe pluck is Ruby 1.9.x and up. Anyone using a previous version won't have it. If you are in 1.9x and above, the ruby docs say this also works: Model.uniq.pluck(:rating)

Comment: `pluck` is a pure Rails > 3.2 method which has no dependency on Ruby 1.9.x See http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Comment: Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.1, so for those on 6.1+ the following should do the trick: `Model.pluck(Arel.sql("DISTINCT rating"))`

Answer (score 41):

If you want to also select extra fields:

```
Model.select('DISTINCT ON (models.ratings) models.ratings, models.id').map { |m| [m.id, m.ratings] }
```

Comment: `select extra fields` <3 <3

Answer (score 29):

```
Model.select(:rating).uniq
```

This code works as 'DISTINCT' (not as Array#uniq) since [rails 3.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L201)

Above Rails 6 (?) it should be

```
Model.select(:rating).distinct
```

Comment: In Rails 6 (At least 6.0.3) this doesn't generate a `DISTINCT` clause, so it's a `SELECT models.rating FROM models` and then Array#uniq

Comment: `Model.select(:rating).distinct` works.

Answer (score 27):

```
Model.uniq.pluck(:rating)

# SELECT DISTINCT "models"."rating" FROM "models"
```

This has the advantages of not using sql strings and not instantiating models

Comment: This throws an error with Rails 5.1 / AR 5.1 => undefined method `uniq'

Answer (score 15):

```
Model.select(:rating).distinct
```

Comment: This is the only officially correct answer that's also super efficient. Although, adding `.pluck(:rating)` at the end will make it exactly what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to collect uniq columns with sql:

```
Model.group(:rating).pluck(:rating)
```

Comment: Upvoted for providing an original solution to the problem. This may even be more performant than a DISTINCT clause depending on the DB.

Answer (score 4):

If I am going right to way then :

Current query

```
Model.select(:rating)
```

is returning array of object and you have written query

```
Model.select(:rating).uniq
```

uniq is applied on array of object and each object have unique id. uniq is performing its job correctly because each object in array is uniq.

There are many way to select distinct rating :

```
Model.select('distinct rating').map(&:rating)
```

or

```
Model.select('distinct rating').collect(&:rating)
```

or

```
Model.select(:rating).map(&:rating).uniq
```

or

```
Model.select(:name).collect(&:rating).uniq
```

One more thing, first and second query : find distinct data by SQL query.

These queries will considered "london" and "london   " same means it will neglect to space, that's why it will select 'london' one time in your query result.

Third and forth query:

find data by SQL query and for distinct data applied ruby uniq mehtod.
these queries will considered "london" and "london   " different, that's why it will select 'london' and 'london  ' both in your query result.

please prefer to attached image for more understanding and have a look on "Toured / Awaiting RFP".

[image]

Comment: `map` & `collect` are aliases for the same method, there is no need to provide examples for both.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for the same with Mongoid, that is

```
Model.distinct(:rating)
```

Comment: this one does not work now, it now returns multiples.

Comment: does not return distinct

Answer (score 3):

Some answers don't take into account the OP wants a **array of values**

Other answers don't work well if your Model has thousands of records

That said, I think a good answer is:

```
    Model.uniq.select(:ratings).map(&:ratings)
    => "SELECT DISTINCT ratings FROM `models` "
```

Because, first you generate a array of Model (with diminished size because of the select), then you extract the only attribute those selected models have (ratings)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following Gem: [active_record_distinct_on](https://github.com/alecdotninja/active_record_distinct_on)

```rb
Model.distinct_on(:rating)
```

Yields the following query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON ( "models"."rating" ) "models".* FROM "models"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I wanted a list of distinct `names` after ordering them by their creation date, applying offset and limit. Basically a combination of `ORDER BY`, `DISTINCT ON`

All you need to do is put `DISTINCT ON` inside the `pluck` method, like follow

`Model.order("name, created_at DESC").offset(0).limit(10).pluck("DISTINCT ON (name) name")`

This would return back an array of distinct `names`.

Answer (score -1):

```rb
Model.pluck("DISTINCT column_name")
```