# Return unique years from find

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails: select unique values from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658881/rails-select-unique-values-from-a-column)

Lets say I have 5000 records that were created in the last two years (2011 & 2012).  How can I loop through all those records and return an array of only the unique years [2011, 2012]?

I'm creating a report where rows are labeled by each year that records exit and columns are labeled by months.  Then td is populated by sum totals for each month of each year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see [Rails: select unique values from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658881/rails-select-unique-values-from-a-column) for a more rails approach..

```
Model.uniq.pluck(:year)
```

edited:

for your specific requirment you can do

```
 Model.pluck(:created_at).map{|x| x.year}.uniq
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about pluck().

Comment: This seems to be looking for a column named 'year'.  No?

Comment: Model.uniq.pluck(:created_at) is getting close.  But, it is returning uniq 'created_at' dates.  I need unique years.  Any ideas?

Comment: oh you dont have a year attribute?

Comment: i've edited the answer to help you more

Comment: I like your updated answer better than using EXTRACT as I did below.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Model.select("created_at").map{ |i| i.created_at.year }.uniq is working.  Im still digging around for a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Went with this solution inspired by RailsN00b.  Model.uniq.pluck("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM whatever_date)")