# Ruby-on-Rails: Selecting distinct values from the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

The docs:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

Clearly state that:

```
query = Client.select(:name).distinct
# => Returns unique names
```

However, when I try that in my controller, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `distinct' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb2f6f2cc>
```

To be clear, I want the distinct names, like ['George', 'Brandon'], not the clients actual records. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]

Comment: That's your Ruby version, which is actually out of date. You should be using 1.9.3 or better. `rails -v` will tell you which version of Rails you're using.

Comment: Another way to select uniq records with Rails you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45593677/5872997)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Rails 2

If you are still on rails 2 you will need to use:

```
Client.select('distinct(name)')
```

### Rails 3

If you are on Rails 3 you will need to use:

```
Client.select(:name).uniq
```

If you look at the equivalent [section of the rails 3 guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) you can see the difference between the two versions.

### Rails 4+

The `.distinct` option was added for rails 4 which is what the latest guides refer to.

```
Client.select(:name).distinct
```

Comment: This will fetch all records from db on Rails 3.

Comment: The guide link explicitly states it will do `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM clients`. Yes, it will fetch all distinct names but it will not fetch all records.

Comment: At least on Rails 7, `select + uniq` returns all records to filter then on app, while `select + distinct` uses DISTINCT in query, returning only uniq list to app

Answer (score 15):

If you do not want ActiveRecord::Relations returned, just an array of the names as strings, then use:

```
Client.distinct.pluck(:name)
```

To get an ordered result set:

```
Client.order(:name).distinct.pluck(:name)
```

Answer (score 14):

There are some approaches:

1. Rails way:

   ```
   Model.select(:name).distinct
   ```
2. Semi-rails way

   ```
   Model.select("DISTINCT ON(models.name) models.*")
   ```

   The second allows you to select the first record uniqued by name, but in the whole matter, not only names.

Answer (score 4):

This will work for Rails 2 (pretty old rails I know!), 3 and 4.

```
Client.select('distinct(name)')
```

This will actually use the SQL select distinct statement

`SELECT distinct name FROM clients`

Comment: this won't always work in the case that you to two select statements : 

scope = Client.select("distinct name"); 
scope = scope.select("address"); 

You can end up with the invalid sql : 

"select address, distinct name from clients"

Comment: Putting `()` around the column solves that problem. Updated my answer. Thanks :)