# Ruby On Rails retrieve mysql database data 'a' distinct 'b'

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, greatest-n-per-group

My database have a device reading list,

columns are id ,device_id ,device_reading ,update_time

How can I select all latest reading for each device?

that means,I need sort data according to update_time first

then I need to filter database use some unique method(unique device_id)

then the I can retrieve device_reading from rows filtered just now.

That is to say, retrieve column a from table where b is distinct

how can I achieve this? in ruby on rails

thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of data stored in device_reading column? True or False?

Comment: Post all the models related with your device reading list will help us to understand this case.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that model name is `DeviceReading`

```
DeviceReading.distinct(:device_id).order('update_time DESC').pluck(:device_reading)
```

You can use `ASC` in place of `DESC` if you want to sort by ascending order

Source: [Distinct and pluck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20714814/2559490) [sort/order](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering)

**EDIT:** The distinct only works in rails 4 so if you are using rails 3 you should do something like this:

```
DeviceReading.select(:device_id).uniq.pluck(:device_reading)
```

**However** when I chain `.order('update_time DESC')` in above I get mysterious error. I am trying to find solution. meanwhile I Hope this helps you.

Source: [distinct undefined error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18004466/2559490)

Comment: when I use it error message says: undefined method `distinct',I use uniq instead,no more error message,but the result seems not filtered--still come out many in a mass

Comment: I have updated my answer. And I have also asked another question related to using `order` with `select` here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616358/rails-3-query-getting-error-while-using-select-with-order

Answer (score 1):

This questions looks quite similar to the one below:

[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

In the case when no elegant solution can be found the Rails way, you can first figure out the correct sql and use `find_by_sql` to retrieve the dataset.

Comment: I won't recommend writing raw SQL in rails because... **(1)** this can be done with rails active-record helper as I have shown in my answer **(2)** When you change the database, you need to change the raw sql as per the new database's syntex

Comment: @Uandl, thanks for the comments. I agree with you that it's not a best practice to directly use SQL in rails application. It should be the last choice with complex queries that Rails doesn't support.