# Unique values from array in column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

This post is close:

[Rails: select unique values from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658881/rails-select-unique-values-from-a-column)

```
Model.uniq.pluck(:rating)
```

works great except in my case my column has an array in it so I get something like this:

```
[["guest"], ["engineer", "manager"], ["engineer"], ["admin"], ["operations"], ["operator"], ["operator", "manager"]]
```

I would like these reduced down to the simplest list (in alphabetical order while we are at it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [Array#`flatten`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten) and [Array#`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort)

```
Model.pluck(:rating).flatten
#=>["guest", "engineer", "manager", "engineer", "admin", "operations", "operator", "operator", "manager"]
```

Now sort it:

```
Model.pluck(:rating).flatten.uniq
#= ["guest", "engineer", "manager", "admin", "operations", "operator"]

Model.pluck(:rating).flatten.uniq.sort
#=> ["admin", "engineer", "guest", "manager", "operations", "operator"]
```

If there could be uppercase words, downcase them while sorting, to make sure sorting is case insensitive:

```
Model.pluck(:rating).flatten.uniq.sort_by(&:downcase)
```