# find rows where there is another row with an opposite value in the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to find an efficient way to solve the problem:

I need to find all rows in a table where there is another row with an opposite column value.

For example I have transactions with columns `id` and `amount`

```
| id | amount |
|----|--------|
| 1  | 1      |
| 2  | -1     |
| 3  | 2      |
| 4  | -2     |
| 5  | 3      |
| 6  | 4      |
| 7  | 5      |
| 8  | 6      |
```

The query should return only the first 4 rows:

```
| id | amount |
|----|--------|
| 1  | 1      |
| 2  | -1     |
| 3  | 2      |
| 4  | -2     |
```

My current solution is terribly efficient as I am going through 1000's of transactions:

```
transactions.find_each do |transaction|
  unless transactions.where("amount = #{transaction.amount * -1}").count > 0
    transactions = transactions.where.not(amount: transaction.amount).order("@ amount DESC")
  end
end
transactions
```

Are there any built in `Rails` or `Postgresql` functions that could help with this?

Comment: I am a newbie. But I have not understood why you chose the 4 first lines. Can you explain ?

Comment: @Maxence each row in those 4 of have another row in the table with an opposite value. `-1` is opposite of `1` for example.

Comment: And you don't need to pair them explicitly? just have them as a batch? (lets say 10 rows have value of 1 and 45 rows have values of -1, you want the 55 rows alltogether?)

Comment: @Maxence yes thats what i need.

Comment: Try to find the unique values instead. like transactions.abs.uniq  (am noob, but this seems good logic). Not sure if can work as uniq seems to work on arrays only.. check this post too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658881/rails-select-unique-values-from-a-column

Answer (score 1):

Use following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
  FROM transactions t1 
  INNER JOIN transactions t2 ON t1.amount = t2.amount * -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM the_table t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM the_table x
    WHERE x.amount = -1*t.amount
    -- AND x.amount > t.amount
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing an absolute value indexed column then query for the positive value.  Postgres has an absolute value function; but I think the beauty of ActiveRecord is that Arel abstracts away the SQL. DB specific SQL can be a pain if you change later.

Answer (score 0):

There is type called `abs` which will return irrespective of symobol. From my example `data` is the table name

```
SELECT id,amount  FROM DATA WHERE id = ABS(amount)
```

This is the sample test table

[image]

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: this doesnt even answer my question.