# How do I combine uniq with select("distinct") without getting an invalid query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to combine a `uniq` statement with a `select("distinct")` statement in Active Record, and it results in two `DISTINCT` keywords, which of course leads to an invalid query. This is the simplest example I have come up with. (Mark that is is simplified in order to help you understand the problem - I'm not simply asking for how I get out distinct ids from a database.)

```
Product.all.uniq.select("distinct id").map(&:id)

This gives me this error message:
 Product Load (0.7ms)  SELECT DISTINCT distinct id FROM "products"
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "distinct"
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT distinct id FROM "products"
                    ^
: SELECT DISTINCT distinct id FROM "products"
```

Why do I get two `DISTRINCT` keywords here? Is there any way to avoid it? Using `uniq` twice works, but I need to do a select for one of the filters I'm implementing.

Edit: The `select("distinct..")` has to go before the `uniq` statement.

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658881/rails-select-unique-values-from-a-column

Comment: No, I1m not. That question asks why models with one field are not equal. I want to know why I get an invalid query from combining plain `uniq` with `select("distinct...")`, and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`uniq` already uses `DISTINCT`. Either use `uniq` or `select("DISTINCT")`. Moreover, you should use `pluck`, and not map over the records and select the `id`.

What you really want to use is

```
Product.pluck(:id)
```

or

```
Product.all.ids
```

What's not clear to me, is why you want to use `distinct`. How comes an ID has duplicate values?

If the field is different than an id, simply use

```
Product.select("DISTINCT(field)").map(&:field)
```

or even better

```
Product.uniq.pluck(:field)
```

Hence in your case

```
Product.uniq.pluck(:id)
# => SELECT DISTINCT "products"."id" FROM "products"
```

Comment: This is a very simplified example in order to make it easier to understand. My real queries are much more advanced, and they are being built up over several lines of code and using scopes from other models. I know that `uniq` adds the `DISTINCT` sql keyword, but I have no way of knowing if one of the scopes added have already used the `uniq` statement or not.

Comment: Then do not oversimplify your example, otherwise we won't be able to provide an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uniq(false)` to disable a previously used `uniq` scope. So your example would go like this:

```rb
scope = Product.all.uniq
scope.uniq(false).select("distinct id").map(&:id)
```

Source code documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L849).

Comment: This works if the `uniq` is added before the `select("distinct...")`, but not after. Unfortunately, that's what I have to do. I'll update the question.

Comment: Well, perhaps you could use `unscope` in that case, something like `Product....select("distinct id").unscope(:select).uniq...`?

Comment: But I want the `select("distinct...")` to be used if it is defined. Am i forces to use a `.to_sql` check?

Comment: So the actual problem is that you want to use `uniq` if `select(distinct...)` has not been defined earlier and vice versa? In that case I'd go the to_sql check, although such usage seems a bit weird....

And by the way, if you used MySQL instead of Postgres, the above query with double `distinct`s would run fine as I've just found out.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot choose what database my customer uses. I guess I'll have to go with the `to_sql` check, then.