# Pluck returning duplicated results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, mysql2

I am facing the following issue. My `game` object has two associated `players`, as we can see:

```
=> game.players.count
2
```

However, the `pluck` method is returning duplicated values:

```
=> game.players.pluck :name
["Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Bob"]
```

Both `Game` and `Player` extend `ActiveRecord::Base`. I have absolutely no idea of what is really going on here.

Relevant gems:

```
rails 4.2.8
mysql2 0.3.21
```

Any clue about what could be going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658881/rails-select-unique-values-from-a-column

Comment: Can you post the output of `game.players`?

Comment: I have finally found out what was going on. However, the output of `game.players` returned just 2 results. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I finally found out that the `Player` model has a `default_scope` that includes the translations from `globalize3` gem:

```
default_scope { includes(:translations) }
```

I removed the default scope and it started working as expected.