# Ruby on Rails get all attributes for uniq User by name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by, null, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I group User by name and get only the most recent User for each name,

```
order(create_at: :desc)
```

I am already grouping my users by name but I can't get only the most recent for each name:

```
User.group(:id, :name).select(:id, :name, :created_at)
```

**[EDIT 01]**

Now I am tryint to get uniq users but also the most recent:
Works!

```
User.order(upadted_at: :desc).uniq{ |u| u.name }
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY This:

`User.select([:id, :name]).order(created_at: :desc).group(:id, :name)`

**or**

```
User.select([:id, :name]).order(:created_at).reverse_order.group(:id, :name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [active record documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) for more but you can do try this:

```
# This will give you the SELECT DISTINCT "users"."name" FROM "users" 
User.distinct.pluck(:name).take(2)

# You can also try this to order by created_at
User.select(:name).order(created_at: :desc)

# You can also take the one that appears first in the most recent 
User.select(:name).order(created_at: :desc).take(1)
```

You should also check this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9658899/5012862)

Hope this helps.