# Get list of unique column results from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, filtering

I've stumbled across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369812/rails-how-can-i-get-unique-values-from-column) and it has helped me to generate a list of unique values exactly as I wanted, however, I don't want all of the results. Is there any way to filter the results within the `select` or another way to accomplish this?

I was thinking of something along the lines of this:

```
@results = MyModel.select("DISTINCT(columnForDistinction)", :myBoolean => false)
```

or

```
@results = MyModel.select("DISTINCT(columnForDistinction)", :someString => stringImLookingFor)
```

Currently, I'm not able to filter the results on the query, so I am iterating over the returned array and only listing the results that have that boolean set to false like so:

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
  <% if !result.myBoolean %>
    #do stuff here
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
  <% if result.someString == stringImLookingFor %>
    #do stuff here
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a better way to be doing this?

Comment: `MyModel.select(:some_field).uniq` that should generate `=> SELECT DISTINCT some_field FROM my_model`

Comment: @Orlando Won't that only return me that field? I want every field, but only the results that meet a certain condition.

Comment: @Orlando And how would that allow me to have an additional condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord query methods are chainable. You can call multiple and it will build them all into a query when you use the result. For conditions, you'll use `where`. Try something like:

```
@results = MyModel.select("DISTINCT(columnForDistinction)").where(:myBoolean => false)
```

Comment: Yeah. I just learned about chaining ActiveRecord queries, so this is what I needed. Does chaining hit the database more than once?

Comment: No, query methods like `select` and `where` return ActiveRecord::Relation objects. Then when you call a method like `each` or `inspect` that needs the actual results, the relation object builds the DB query with all the chained stuff and runs it. I also recommend reading up about scopes.