# Rails get latest n posts per tag

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

```
class Post
has_many :tags 

class Tag
belongs_to :post
```

I need a query that returns all posts limited to n per tag.

Given the following set of posts (tagged with hashtags like on Twitter):

```
#1: Post A #letter 
#2: Post B #letter
#3: Post 1 #number 
#4: Post C #letter 
#5: Post 2 #number
```

I would want to get all of the latest 2 posts per tag, giving me the following result:

```
#5: Post 2 #number 
#4: Post C #letter 
#3: Post 1 #number 
#2: Post B #letter
```

I've been looking up how to do this for a few hours now, but only found results (like [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)) that use MySQL variables and don't know how to translate it to Rails.

I still don't know where to begin tackling this so any help is appreciated; thanks!

Comment: Read the excellent http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: @summea No, if I use group like in the accepted answer, it would only return one post per tag whereas I'm looking to get multiple (e.g., 5) posts per tag.

Comment: @tag.posts.order('id desc').limit(5).reverse

Comment: I clarified the question a little more. I'm looking to get the latest n posts for all tags.

Comment: Are you supplying the tags yourself or do you want 'n' latest posts for each tag that exists in db?

Comment: @erosenin The latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
def get_tags(n)
  Tags.order('id desc').select("DISTINCT(NAME)").each do |tag|
    Post.where(tag: tag).limit(n)
  end
end
```

This link may help you, if not work
[Unique select from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369812/rails-how-can-i-get-unique-values-from-column)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try:

```
 @post = Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: {name: "letter"}).order(created_at: :desc).limit(2)
```

This uses the [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) ActiveRecord method, with the [hash conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) on the `where` clause, [ordering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) by created_at (to give latest), and [limiting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset) the response to 2 records

This should work for a single tag; if you wanted to extend to multiple tags, I'd use the SQL method `GROUP_BY`, (ActiveRecord [`.group`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group)), like this:

```
 @post = Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: {name: "letter", name: "number"}).order(created_at: :desc).group("tags.name").limit(2)
```