# Get all columns of each distinct records in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to get distinct records in rails.
For that I see this [Rails: how can I get unique values from column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369812/rails-how-can-i-get-unique-values-from-column)

But the issue is that by this solution I only get the Ids .

```
ViewsLog.uniq.pluck(:unit_id)
[24, 21, 23, 4, 16, 5, 7]
```

I want all columns of uniq unit_id

Comment: Distinct records based on what? What does your model look like?

Comment: My model is ["id", "user_id", "unit_id", "unit_type", "is_billed", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_credit", "deleted_at", "campaign_id"] and I want all distinct records on unit_id

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `group`; it gives you all distinct records:

```
 ViewsLog.group(:unit_id)
```

Comment: Is it only applicable on primary keys?
Because when I do this it gives an error
G::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "surveys.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: if your using `primary_key` then there is no chances of repetition of same id again n again it is handled by database. and it is applicable for all types of columns

Comment: NO NO this isnt primary key

Comment: @HaseebAhmad which database you are using?? and i think you are trying to select other columns that are not present in query

Comment: Postgresql...No I write the same query

Comment: @HaseebAhmad i think you are attached tag of `mysql` i am not sure it is working in `Postgresql`

Comment: Yes according to myql its fine..n I find its equivalent in postgresql ....Thanks :)

Comment: @VishalJAIN You can use group on only the column which are using in select statement or if you using aggregate functions. 

To get distinct record check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

In rails to get distinct record can be used

```
ViewsLog.distinct(:unit_id)
```

If you are using postgres and have json type in a table then need to write like follow

```
ViewsLog.select('distinct on (views_logs.unit_id) views_logs.*')
```

Because postgres is not supporting to distinct if there is a json type filed in your table.

Comment: `distinct` is giving a error in `rails 3.2` from which version of rails this feature is supporting??

Comment: `ViewsLog.select('distinct on (views_logs.unit_id) views_logs.*')`
  Does not work in Rails 6.0.3.1 either